# Async code testing using testNg

Tags: java, testing, asynchronous

Does testing provide a way to test async code?

Case: Request/response between Client and server can happen in async mode.
I am writing tests like `testDifferentPayload`, `testDifferentHeaders`, `testDifferentConfig` in a class using TestNG. Currently each of the tests is waiting till response from server.

I can run the tests in parallel to speed this up but is there any better way to do async code testing using testNg?
I am looking something like in test methods I can do just async call like `sendMessageToServer` and do asserts in a common callback method for all tests.

Comment: Is this of any help: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-extreme-programming/0596003870/ch04s15.html ?